# Which is the best, most efficient method of concatenation?

Tags: python, concatenation

I find myself almost always favoring *Method 1* over the others.  For a sense of understanding, it would be helpful to know the performance differences between each method.

```py
string = "Hello"


# Method 1:

concat = f"{string} World"


# Method 2:

concat = " ".join([string, "World"])


# Method 3:

concat = "%s World" % (string)


# Method 4:

concat = "{} World".format(string)


# Method 5:

concat = string + " World"
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to test each methods performance  on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little experiment, and got some results:

Code:

```
from time import perf_counter

string = "Hello"

# Method 1:
timer = perf_counter()
for _ in range(1000000):
    concat = f"{string} World"
stop = perf_counter()
print(stop-timer)


# Method 2:
timer = perf_counter()
for _ in range(1000000):
    concat = " ".join([string, "World"])
stop = perf_counter()
print(stop-timer)


# Method 3:
timer = perf_counter()
for _ in range(1000000):
    concat = "%s World" % (string)
stop = perf_counter()
print(stop-timer)


# Method 4:
timer = perf_counter()
for _ in range(1000000):
    concat = "{} World".format(string)
stop = perf_counter()
print(stop-timer)


# Method 5:
timer = perf_counter()
for _ in range(1000000):
    concat = string + " World"
stop = perf_counter()
print(stop-timer)
```

Output:

```
============================ RESTART: C:/Users/User/Desktop/test.py ============================
1.4445583890000002
2.1913094359999996
2.3903527139999996
3.1563172369999997
1.2841627659999997
>>> 
============================ RESTART: C:/Users/User/Desktop/test.py ============================
1.4030118260000002
2.225838672
2.385356615
3.135374066
1.3409891600000012
>>> 
============================ RESTART: C:/Users/User/Desktop/test.py ============================
1.4127473929999999
2.2778024140000004
2.4126252360000002
3.1423811290000003
1.3086146010000004
>>> 
============================ RESTART: C:/Users/User/Desktop/test.py ============================
1.4890592930000002
2.2285004519999996
2.444464975
3.203428595
1.279161534
```

The last number in each test run (`Method 5`), is always the smallest.